# How to create stacked progress bar with white (transparent) color inside using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I can create stacked progress bar like this one (please, don't ask me why).

[image: stacked progress bar]

But how to change some of this colors to white and place inside?
Seems like there is no easy ways according to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the styles. You can override the class.

example

```
.progress-bar-warning {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Finally I've got transparency using `.progress-bar-primary { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) !important; }`